# How to get the header and navbar on top?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm getting into HTML + CSS and I'm learning how to code. I simply want to get my header and nav bar at the top of the page. I have researched for a few days and nothing seems to be working.

Here's my HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="aboutmecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>




<body>
<header>
<h2>My website</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="activemenutab"> <a href="aboutme.html">About Me </a></li>
        <li> <a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments </a></li>
        <li> <a href="certs.html">Certifications and Skills </a></li>
        <li> <a href="extra.html">Extracirriculars </a></li>
        <li> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio </a></li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</header>



    <footer>
          &copy; 2015
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";



html {
    background-color:#B5B5B5
}

header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0; 
    margin:0;
}

h2 {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#d9d9d9;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none; /* takes symbols away from unordered list */
    margin:0; /* shifts ul up against h2, and shifts it up in the header box */
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    font-family:Baskerville, serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:absolute; /*drags bar over for the left and right commands below */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center; /* centers nav bar */
    font-size:0; /* this takes away the default white spaces at the end of the <li>...have to resize font in li */
}

li {
    display:inline-block; /* makes nav go horizontal */
    font-size:14px; /* size of navbar text ... !important has to be in px because ul has font size = 0*/

}

li:hover {
    background:#000000; /* changes tab to black */
    color:#E09635; /* changes text to color */
    transition-duration: 0.3s; /* response time on navbar icon hover */
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0; /* zero delay to have transtion occur */
}

a {
    text-decoration:none; /*removes underline from a links */
    color:inherit; /* takes color from parent, in this case, li */
    display:block; /* makes the a box relatable to li */
    padding: 10px;  /* creates padding around a box for navbar and adds to clickable region because of anchor */
}

.activemenutab { /* this is the class used to make the one you are on highlighted ... needs to be swithched in html */
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    color:#E09635;
}

/* ---------- body below */

/* ---------- footer below */

footer {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#EDEDED;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:.2em;
}
```

All i want to do is have the Header at the complete top of the browser, and my navbar under it. I've tried a whole bunch of stuff, and the other proper format I can get it is when I use this in CSS

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely honest I have no idea why there is a gap there. There shouldn't be. But I did take your code and edited it and came up with a cheaphax that worked.

Just did a little tinkering and added

`margin-top:-42px;`

in your css in both your header and ul properties. Tested it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `margin: 0;` to `h2`.

```
h2 {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#d9d9d9;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5t5nov9/)

Comment: This helped me bring the UL (navbar) + header together. There still remains a sliver of space above. Could it be default browser settings?

Comment: Check in developer tools, but it could be default browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this instead of the `head` element:

```
<div class="header"> ... </div>
```

Then in your style sheet, just rename `header` to be `.header`

like so:

```
.header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0; 
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: `<header>` is html element and it worked fine in example

Comment: well I'll be, it is! (still living in HTML 4 land I guess ;) ).  Anyway, it's worth trying for the styling attempt

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gk4zLdyu/)

```
.header {
position:relative;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag must have an id or class. Change it to:

```
<div class="header">
```

When referencing it in your css you'd put:

```
.header {
*your code*
}
```